# Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I am trying to install the BETA version of ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 by following stanard installation instructions but end up with:
Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full

It looks like everything is online and there's just no desktop-full on the repo. Is there any other way to currently install and test ros-melodic without building from source?

EDIT:
Building from source also did not work for me:

```
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar > melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: desktop_full
No packages/stacks left after ignoring not released

$ wstool init -j8 src melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall 
Using initial elements from: melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
WARNING: Not using any element from melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall
Writing /home/arek/ros_catkin_ws/src/.rosinstall

update complete.

$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
bash: ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289938/unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full/) by [ArkadiuszN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29844/arkadiuszn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Anyone know what's wrong?

Nothing is really "wrong": there just isn't a version of `desktop_full` released for Melodic. The fact that the installation instructions won't work yet is also clearly stated at the top of the [ROS Melodic installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation) page:

> **CAUTION**: Release of this distribution is pending.

> ROS Melodic Morenia has not been fully released yet, so these instructions will not entirely work.

Trying to build this from source is not going to change it: `rosinstall_generator` won't be able to find a `desktop_full` package (as it can only build packages that have been released).

To install Melodic packages, you can check [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html) to see which packages have been released (this page is also linked from the Melodic install page, under section *Build farm status*). See [status_page/blocked_releases_melodic.html](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/blocked_releases_melodic.html?s=6&r=1) to see why something hasn't/can't be released into Melodic yet.

> Is there any other way to currently install and test ros-melodic without building from source?

Yes: install individual packages for now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ArkadiuszN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29844/arkadiuszn/) on 2018-04-28**:
Oh, I get it. According to [Melodic Planning](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Planning) there's no beta yet, my mistake. Thank you for your answer.

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-13**:
So it's 2020 and this still doesn't work, even though it has been released.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-13**:
Do you expect any assistance?

Because if you do, then:

- you should post a new question
- provide much more information

**Comment by [James Newton](https://answers.ros.org/users/57187/james-newton/) on 2020-07-31**:
That message is no longer on that page. Melodic full IS now released.